# What is the best way to achieve a true orange color using malt in a 5 gallon batch oh home brew

Tags: brewing

I have a HERM system and brew all grain batches. A local brewer makes a very good orange colored all Mosaic IPA. I am curious how they achieve the color.

Answer (score 2):

Victory malt will give you a great orange color. 
I have an IPA fermenting at the moment which looks awesome with 4.8% Victory, but could probably bump this up a little further.